# change array values after explode in yii2

Tags: php, html, yii2, explode

I have a problem regarding insertion of data after explode. In this gridview column, I throw function in value like this:

```
    [
        'attribute' => 'CONNECTOR_ACTION',
        'value' => function($model){
             $apps = \app\models\APPLICATION::find()
                 ->where(['ID' => $model->ID_APPLICATION])
                 ->one();
             $options = $apps['CONNECTOR_PARAM'];
             $optionsArr = explode(', ', $options);
             return Html::activeDropDownList($model, 'CONNECTOR_ACTION', $optionsArr, ['class'=>'form-control', 'disabled' => true]);
        },
                            'format' => 'raw'
    ],
```

And in HTML view like this:

```
<td>
    <select id="requestapplication-connector_action" class="form-control" name="REQUESTAPPLICATION[CONNECTOR_ACTION]" disabled>
        <option value="0">create</option>
        <option value="1">addrole</option>
        <option value="2">defaultrole</option>
        <option value="3">removerole</option>
        <option value="4" selected>disable</option>
        <option value="5">enable</option>
        <option value="6">setpassword</option>
    </select>
</td>
```

If I want to change dropdown like this:

```
<td>
    <select id="requestapplication-connector_action" class="form-control" name="REQUESTAPPLICATION[CONNECTOR_ACTION]" disabled>
        <option value="create">create</option>
        <option value="addrole">addrole</option>
        <option value="defaultrole">defaultrole</option>
        <option value="removerole">removerole</option>
        <option value="disable" selected>disable</option>
        <option value="enable">enable</option>
        <option value="6">setpassword</option>
    </select>
</td>
```

How do I do that?

Comment: you need to create array with key same as value using some traversing logic

Comment: Thanks for your answer. That's a clue and I have solve my problem \m/

Comment: you can use **jagsler** 's answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because the keys of `$optionsArr` are 0-6 instead of the values. To combine it set the keys the same as the values.

```
$combined = array_combine($optionsArr, $optionsArr);
```

And then use `$combined` in `Html::activeDropdownList()`